# Join & Subquery to calculate Minimum datediff

Tags: sql, datediff

I have 2 SQL tables, one for `subscribers (ID, Name)`, second for `subscribers_Upgrades [Subscriber_ID (FK), Upgrade_Level, Upgrade_Date)`

(There are 7 upgrade levels)

I need a query to get the top 10 subscribers who upgraded in the shortest period and `Upgrade_Level`, and `Upgrade Date` for specific `Upgrade_Level` (any one of the available 7 Upgrade level), and within specific period of time

We can, for example supply the 2 conditions like
`Where Upgrade_Level = 3 and Upgrade_Date between '01-April-2014' and '20-May-2016'`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: "SQ" is a query language, not a DBMS. Every relational database uses SQL as their query language.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean shortest period? Who have upgraded in earliest time in upgrade_date order?

```
SELECT TOP 10 s.ID, 
    s.Name, 
    su.UpgradeLevel, 
    su.UpgradeDate 
    FROM Subscribers s 
    INNER JOIN SubscribersUpgrades su on s.ID = su.SubscriberId
    WHERE su.UpgradeLevel = 3 AND su.UpgradeDate BETWEEN '01-April-2014' AND '20-May-2016'
    ORDER BY su.UpgradeDate ASC
```

**UPDATE**

If you need data only for 2 upgrade level (level 2 and 3) this should work -

```
SELECT TOP 10 s.Name, DATEDIFF(dd,t1.UpgradeDate,t2.UpgradeDate) UpgradePeriodInDays FROM

(SELECT su.SubscriberId, su.UpgradeDate FROM SubscribersUpgrades su
WHERE su.UpgradeLevel = 2 ) t1

INNER JOIN (SELECT su.SubscriberId, su.UpgradeDate FROM SubscribersUpgrades su
WHERE su.UpgradeLevel = 3) t2 on t1.SubscriberId = t2.SubscriberId

INNER JOIN Subscribers s on t1.SubscriberId = s.ID

WHERE t2.UpgradeDate BETWEEN '01-June-2016' AND '20-July-2016'
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,t1.UpgradeDate,t2.UpgradeDate) ASC
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mr.Nayen for you response but I mean the subscribers who take short period to upgrade to level 3 from Level 2 since (assuming we need to get subscribers who upgrade faster to level 3)

we have the time for each upgrade in column [Upgrade_Date], and Subscriber_ID as a foreign key


and to be more accurate upgrade levels aren't int type they are nvarchar and exactly as below:

1- Basic
2- Pre-Intermidate
3- Intermidate
4- Advanced
5- One Star Advanced Manager
6- Two Star Advanced Manager
7- Three Star Advanced Manager